# What is the idea of verify in mockito and when should I use it

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I understand that *Mockito.verify()* is used to ensure that a mock method is being called with required arguments. But I don't understand the intention of this. I often see tests similar to this:

```
public class UserDAO {
    public long create(User user) {
        //...
    }
}

public class UserService {
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public UserService(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public long createUser(User user) {
        return userDAO.create(user);
    }
}

public class UserServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        UserDAO userDAO = mock(UserDAO.class);
        when(userDAO.create(any(User.class))).thenReturn(anyLong());

        UserService = new UserService(userDAO);
        User user = new User("John Smith");
        userService.createUser(user);

        verify(userDAO).create(user);
    }
}
```

Test verifies that *create* method of *UserDAO* is invoked when *createUser* method of *UserService* is invoked. It looks absurd. If I change the implementation of *UserService* in such way that it doesn't invoke method of *UserDAO* my test will fail even if the implementation is correct.

I admit that there might be cases when it's necessary to verify that method is invoked exact number of times but such cases are infrequent.

Most likely I don't understand the idea of *verify* and it's not a mockito-specific feature. Could you explain it in simple words and when it really makes sense to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The `verify()` method is a tool for kind of whitebox testing. But it's not the actual implementation you want to test, but to test, whether a certain kind of *message* (method invocation) is send to an underlying layer or - to be more precise - to *specify the use of an API as a result of the execution of your code under test*.

Tests typically consist of the following steps:

- prepare the input (input params, environment, (mock)systems, etc),
- invoke the code to test
- compare the actual results (output params, changes to environment) against the expected results (a set of assumptions)

But the expected results don't have to be necessarily some output data but some changes to the environment. But if you've mocked the environment you need to define, how the environment is affected by your code and typically access to the environment (or other components) is done via APIs.

Let's take the `create` method as example. The method has no return value, but the assumption is, that a dataset has been created on the underlying data layer (the environment). When you've mocked the data layer, how would you verify that some data has been stored when there is no storage? So under the assumption that there is no other option for store the data (from perspective of your component) than to invoke the `create` method, it is fair to assume, that the `create` method has to be invoked in order to store data. Thus `verify(yourComponent).create()` is a prove that the execution of your code is correct. Of course, this requires the knowledge, that a certain API is used (providing the `create` method), therefore it's kind of a whitebox testing.

There are additional use cases:

- number of invocations (i.e. 10 items passed, assume that 10 items are added: 
  `verify(list, times(10)).add(any(Item.class))`
- capturing of arguments, i.e. to assert a certain transformation happened or the right arguments gets passed, and you require access to the argument

  `ArgumentCaptor<ExpectedType> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ExpectedType.class);
  verify(theApi).apiMethod(captor.capture());
  ExpectedType passedParam = captor.getValue();`
- verify a method has *not* been invoked (i.e. on certain conditions, combined with a positive test)
- verify a method with certain arguments has been invoked (= a specific message has been send): `verify(subject).method(eq("param1"), eq("param2"))`

But all boil down to specify the use of an API in order to specify which messages are expected to be sent to another component or system and *NOT* to specify every single line of the implementation in test (which would be pointless).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of this `UserServiceTest` is to test the implementation of it. So yes you do want to verify that you do call the `create` method of the `UserDAO` interface.